# The Javascript Profile Lookup challenge

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck here for a while, and I checked on other solutions which matched mine perfectly. But I can't seem to find the error in my code as it keeps saying..

```
// running tests
lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName") should return the string Vos
lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes") should return ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes") should return an array
// tests completed
```

This is the challenge...

```
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];
```

My code...

```
function lookUpProfile(name,prop){

  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return contacts[i][prop];
    } else if (contacts[i].firstName === name && !contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return "No such property";
    }
    return "No such contact";

  }
  // Only change code above this line
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

The test parameters

```
lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName") should return the string Vos

lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes") should return ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]

lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes") should return an array

lookUpProfile("Bob", "number") should return the string No such contact

lookUpProfile("Bob", "potato") should return the string No such contact

lookUpProfile("Akira", "address") should return the string No such property
```

Please I'd be so glad if anyone can help open my eyes.

Comment: Looks like your `lookUpProfile` function gives up after the first iteration if it doesn't find the contact.

Comment: `return "No such contact"` should not be inside the loop.

Comment: I recommend using `contacts.find()` to find the contact by its name. Then use `hasOwnProperty()` to test if `prop` exists.

Comment: Recommendation: Use a debugger. Then you can execute your code step by step, look at variables etc. and see what it does. You would then notice things like these much easier.

Comment: You should loop and check the contents of the profile ONLY after you found the correct element of the array based on the first name. This, of course, will not work if you have two persons with the same first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were prematurely ending your function if you didn't find the contact in the first iteration. You were close to getting it to work:

```js
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {

  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
  {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) 
    {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    } 
    else if (contacts[i].firstName === name && !contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) 
    {
      return "No such property";
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";

  // Only change code above this line
}


console.log( lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName") );

console.log( lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes") );

console.log( lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes") );

console.log( lookUpProfile("Bob", "number") );

console.log( lookUpProfile("Bob", "potato") );

console.log( lookUpProfile("Akira", "address") );
```

Comment: Thanks @LeeTaylor, pushed back the return statement "No such contact" down a line of code i definitely was ending the loop prematurely by using the return statement there. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem. You were so close to getting it working. I would **highly** recommend spending an hour or more learning to use your browser's dev tools. You can add breakpoints which allow you to "freeze" or step-through your code, line by line. Learning to debug your own code is half the battle!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [the nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```js
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  const profile = contacts?.find(contact => contact.firstName === name);
  return profile?.[prop] ?? "No such property";
}

const results = [
  lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"), // should return the string Vos
  lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes"), // should return ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"), // should return an array
  lookUpProfile("Bob", "number"), // should return the string No such contact
  lookUpProfile("Bob", "potato"), // should return the string No such contact
  lookUpProfile("Akira", "address"), // should return the string No such property
];

results.forEach(result => console.log(result));
```